# How to copy files between remotes with params

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface, scp

I want to copy all directories from one remote to another using scp

```
scp -r -3 remote1:/dir1 remote2:/dir1
```

But in couple of days i will copy new files. But scp overwrites existing files. Can somebody help me to set right params to copy only those files which are -mtime +N

Thanks

Comment: Use `rsync` instead of scp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of such option in `scp`. If rsync is an option then try:

```
ssh remote1 'rsync -aH /dir1/ remote2:/dir1/'
```

If you do not have connection between `remote1` and `remote2`, the task is still possible with `rsync`, but a whole lot harder. Try this:

```
ssh -R 127.0.0.1:12345:remote2:22 remote1 \
    'rsync -e "ssh -p 12345" -aH /dir1 127.0.0.1:/dir1'
```

NB: the `\` on the first line continues the command to the second line. The command does the following:

1. ssh `-R 127.0.0.1:12345:remote2:22` ... - ssh will bind to `127.0.0.1:1234` and forward all connections trough your machine (where you start the command) to `remote2:22`.
2. ... `rsync -e "ssh -p 12345" -aH /dir1 127.0.0.1:/dir1` - ssh will start this command on `remote1`.
3. rsync `-e "ssh -p 12345"` - this tells rsync to use ssh on port 12345 to connect to the remote machine.
4. ... -aH `/dir1 127.0.0.1:/dir1` - this makes rsync sync between `/dir1` and `127.0.0.1:/dir1`.

So rsync connects to `127.0.0.1:12345` on `remote1`, ssh forwards this to `remote2:22`. So your `ssh` does the proxy-ing between the two hosts. Hope I managed to explain it...

Comment: I don't have connection between host1 and host2

Comment: Well, it is still possible, but a lot harder :-) I edited the response.

Comment: Thanks! I will try and answer here

Comment: You may, of course, want to add `--delete` and other options to `rsync` :-)

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps

```
scp `find BLABLA -mtime TIME` USER@HOST:
```

Adjust as needed.